# Okta introspect endpoint always returns false

Tags: openid-connect, okta

I'm attempting to validate a freshly obtained Okta OIDC access token using their `/introspect` endpoint as documented [here](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oidc/#introspect). I know the token is good because I just got it from the browser's debugger after authenticating.

Not sure why, but the endpoint is always returning `false` —i.e.

```json
{
    "active": false
}
```

I'm trying this from Postman. Here's the `curl` snippet generated by Postman.

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'https://dev-359971.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/introspect' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'token=eyJr...yJPg' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=0*****************7'
```

I've found this same question asked in Okta's help center [here](https://support.okta.com/help/s/question/0D51Y00006QNC11SAH/introspect-url-always-returning-false), but whatever the solution was, it has never posted.

**UPDATE:**

I should mention that my Okta app is configured as an SPA, so there's no `client_secret`. Which is why there's no `Authorization` header in my cURL call. According to the Okta docs [here](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oidc/#request-parameters-3):

> For public clients (such as single-page and mobile apps) that don't have a `client_secret`, you must include the `client_id` as a query parameter when calling the `/introspect` endpoint. Make sure that you aren't passing the `Authorization` header in the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shout-out to @GaryArcher for getting me closer to the answer.

The problem was that I was failing to specify a URI that included what —in Okta terminology— is referred to as the *"Custom Authorisation Server"*.

Meaning, I was using `/oauth2/v1/introspect` as an endpoint, when I should be using `/oauth2/${authServerId}/v1/introspect` —which in my case ends up being `/oauth2/default/v1/introspect`, because I'm using the `default` authorisation header.

The Okta docs [here](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oidc/#composing-your-base-url) explain how to compose your base URI, and there it says that for the use case where *"Okta as the identity platform for your app or API"* —which is my case:

> for use cases where Okta is the authorization server for your resource server (for example, you want Okta to act as the user store for your application, but Okta is invisible to your users). This kind of authorization server we call a "Custom Authorization Server", and your base URL looks like this: `https://${yourOktaDomain}/oauth2/${authServerId}`

It should be noted that if you try to use the [Postman collections that Okta offers](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/postman-collections/) for download —which is what I tried—, the `authServerId` is not included in the URI's. Which is what threw me off.

I hope this helps others.

Comment: Worked! That was just the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example from my dev account, where I am using the default Authorization Server. You need to send both a client_id and client_secret and it is standard to configure them in a Basic Authorization header:

**VISUALLY**

Key things to understand about the message are highlighted below:

[image]

**CURL**

This works for me from the command line if I insert the correct values:

```
curl --request POST --user myclientid:myclientsecret \
https://dev-843469.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/introspect \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode token=XXX
```

**API OAUTH REGISTRATION**

You also need to register the API as an introspection client in Okta - as in [Step 6 of my blog post](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/15/developer-domain-setup/).

**LIBRARIES**

Any decent library will do most of the work for you, such as the NodeJS [Open Id Client](https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client):

- [Example NodeJS API Introspection Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authenticator.ts)

Comment: Thank you, @GaryArcher. I should  have mentioned that in my case the Okta app is an SPA one, so there's no `client_secret`. Still, your answer was useful. Reading it I realised I was missing the authorisation server in my URL —i.e. the `/default` part of it. Not sure why the Okta API still responds without that, but it does and it's a bit misleading.